# Kubuntu 11.10 Internet Sharing via Wireless

Tags: wireless, kubuntu

I just setup fresh kubuntu 11.10. I have a wired internet in my apartment but need to do wireless internet sharing from kubuntu (laptop i using) to another mac book pro. I can't find the solution that match what I need. Anyone have some good guide or solution :) for this.

Comment: Found a solution for Xubuntu 10.04 in [this thread on Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1493249), I am guessing the idea is the same. Try and give it a shot.

Answer (score 1):

Your wifi adapter won't let you connect to 2 networks at the same time so you can't do this 100% wifi (it can be an access point OR a guest but not both at the same time).

So you will need to connect your notebook to internet wired and share wifi or connect wifi to internet and the other machine wired (or blue tooth as commented) (or to a 2nd wifi router sharing internet).

The best option would be to share the wifi router connection directly if possible (if you have access to it) or place a second router wired to the first (or a wifi bridge router able to do both connections at the same time) you can control and share internet from it to both machines.

Comment: I can't connect the router. Because I use apartment's internet.

Comment: So I think your best option is the one from the 3rd part of my answer, use a wi-fi bridge router to connect to the appartment router and share from it.

Answer (score 0):

While this (http://kubuntuforums.net/forums/index.php?topic=3111720.0) is an older post it might help you out as well.  I know in the past when I've traveled I plugged my netbook into the wired connection and created the ad hoc connection with network manager.

Hopefully it helps?

Comment: I go to the link you paste. But not found (404). Could you please paste the link again.:)